# Is it possible to use Oracle EXECUTE IMMEDIATE on command created with SELECT?

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider an Oracle 11gR2 database that has a bunch of expired user accounts.  I want to re-enable all the user accounts without changing any passwords.

Here's a SQL statement to create a string of `ALTER USER` SQL statements that could be executed to re-enable the accounts:

```
select listagg( cmds, ' ' ) within group ( order by rownum )
    as cmd
from (
    select
        'alter user "' || d.username || '"' ||
            ' identified by values ''' || u.password || '''' ||
            ' account unlock;'
    as
        cmds
    from
        dba_users d, sys.user$ u
    where
        d.user_id = u.user#
);
```

The result of this query is a string containing entries that look like:

`alter user "USERNAME" identified by values '1234567890ABCDEF' account unlock; ...`

I'm sure a PL/SQL procedure could be created to store the result of this query to a variable, and then call `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE [var]`, but is it possible via some SQL syntax magic to get `EXECUTE IMMEDATE` to simply execute the string created by the `SELECT` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a stored procedure, you can use an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
DECLARE
   stmt varchar(5000);
   cursor get_users
   is
    select d.username, u.password
    from dba_users d
        join sys.user$ u d.user_id = u.user#
    where lock_date is not null;
   user_rec get_users%rowtype;

BEGIN
    FOR user_rec in get_users loop
    BEGIN
       stmt := 'alter user "' || user_rec.username || '"' ||
               ' identified by values ''' || user_rec.password || '''' || 
               ' account unlock';
       execute immediate stmt;
     EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Error unlocking '||user_rec.username);
        dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
     END;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was thinking would have to be done, namely that execute immediate can't be fed a command constructed inline.

Answer (score 1):

SQL generating SQL like this works, don't know if it fits your needs:

```
sqlplus -s user/pw@db
set heading off
set feedback off 
set pages 0
spool cmd.sql
select ...
spool off
@cmd.sql
```

Comment: I accepted a_horse_with_no_name's answer because it was closer to what I was looking for but this is a great solution.  If I could accept both answers I would.  In many respects (provided sqlplus is accessible), I think this method is actually preferable.